# Long subfigure references

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

In a certain part of my current document I need to reference a figure that is composed of 18 small pngs. Sometimes I need to reference some subfigures in the same sentence and I end up with text like this:

> "see Figures 4.3d, 4.3e, 4.3g, 4.3m, 4.3n, 4.3p, 4.3q, and
>   4.3r"

Is there any way to remove the unnecessary repetition of '4.3' and end up with something like this?

> "see Figures 4.3d, e, g, m, n, p, q, and r"

or like this?

> "see Figures 4.3d-e, g, m-r"

I'm aware that both are quite ugly solutions, so I'm willing to accept any better typesetting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use the [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[test\label{sfig:a}]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}}    \subfloat[test\label{sfig:b}]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}}    \subfloat[test\label{sfig:c}]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}}\\
\subfloat[test\label{sfig:d}]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}}    \subfloat[test\label{sfig:e}]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}}    \subfloat[test\label{sfig:f}]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}}\\
\subfloat[test\label{sfig:g}]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}}    \subfloat[test\label{sfig:h}]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}}    \subfloat[test\label{sfig:i}]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
\caption{A test caption}
\end{figure}

As we can see in \cref{sfig:a,sfig:b,sfig:c,sfig:e,sfig:g,sfig:h,sfig:i}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect thanks. Is it possible to customize the "separator" that cleveref uses?

Comment: @AlbertoMiranda You're welcome! Regarding the question about the separator, for example, if you want an en-dash (and no spaces) instead of "to " for a range, you can add `\def\crefrangeconjunction{--}` to the preamble.